# How can I fix these compiler errors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got in my Unity 2d project 3 compiler errors i do not know how to fix. These are as follow:
[image: compiler errors]  I got those in two c# classes which I hope will show here

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera camera;
    private new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private Vector2 velocity;

    private float inputAxis;



    public float moveSpeed = 8f;
    public float maxJumpHeight = 5f;
    public float maxJumpTime = 1f;

    public float jumpForce => (2f * maxJumpHeight) / (maxJumpTime / 2f);
    public float gravity => (-2f * maxJumpHeight) / Mathf.Pow((maxJumpTime / 2f), 2);

    public bool grounded { get; private set; }
    public bool jumping { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        camera = Camera.main;
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        HorizontalMovement();

        grounded = rigidbody.Raycast(Vector2.down);

        if (grounded)
        {
            GroundedMovement();

        }

        ApplyGravity();
    }

    private void HorizontalMovement()
    {

        inputAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        velocity.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocity.x, inputAxis * moveSpeed, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    private void GroundedMovement()
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Max(velocity.y, 0f);
        jumping = velocity.y > 0f;

        if (inputAxis.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            velocity.y = jumpForce;
            jumping = true;
        }


    }

    private void ApplyGravity()
    {
        bool falling = velocity.y < 0f;
        float multiplier = falling ? 2f : 1f;

        velocity.y += gravity * multiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.y = Mathf.Max(velocity.y, gravity / 2f);

    }

   private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 position = rigidbody.position;
        position += velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        //basically, applies velocity over time

        Vector2 leftEdge = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector2.zero);
        Vector2 rightEdge = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, leftEdge.x + 0.5f, rightEdge.x -0.5f); 
        rigidbody.MovePosition(position);
    }


}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Extensions
{
    private static LayerMask layerMaske = layerMaske.GetMask("Default");
    public static bool Raycast(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody, Vector2 direction)
    {
        if (rigidbody.isKinematic)
        {
            return false;
        }
        float radius = 0.25;
        float distance = 0.375f;

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(rigidbody.position, radius, direction, distance, layerMaske);
        return hit.collider != null && hit.rigidbody != rigidbody;
    }
}
```

here.
Please keep in mind I'm new to  both the stackoverflow community and Unity/coding.
Please apologize if I did some mistakes with copying my code or pasting the screenshot and thank you for advance for answering.

I tried to solve these errors on my own but with my low experience and knowledge in coding, it could not be fixed.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Errors messages should be posted as text, formatted appropriately You also need to specify exactly where each error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the errors in order, read what they say, and act accordingly:

---

> Member 'LayerMask.GetMask(params string[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

In your code, you are doing this:

```cs
private static LayerMask layerMaske = layerMaske.GetMask("Default");
```

This should be `LayerMask.GetMask` since `GetMask` is a static method. (And even if it wasn't, this would still fail because you can't use an instance variable within its own declaration.)

---

> Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'l use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type.

In your code, you are doing this:

```cs
float radius = 0.25;
```

A decimal number literal without the `f` suffix is a `double`, and you cannot assign a `double` value to a `float` variable without an explicit cast. Unity recommends using `float` whenever possible anyway, so it should be `0.25f`.

---

> 'float' does not contain a definition for 'GetButtonDown' and no accessible extension method 'GetButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type...

In your code, you are doing:

```cs
if (inputAxis.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
```

This is merely a typo. It should be `Input.GetButtonDown(...)`.

---

All of these errors basically amount to typos. The error messages are there for you to self-diagnose these kinds of simple errors, and your IDE should also be showing you red squigglies where they are happening. These tools are your friends.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer of my "silly" questions and apologizes for not marking the error in my code and answering just now. I didn't thnik of marking the errors and didn't log in into stackoverflow because I got busy of school and other events I had. Thank you.